# I got a ModuleNotFoundError when running a program cloned from one of my Github repos

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently cloned one of my repositories and tried running the program on a different device than the one I created it on and encountered this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named cryptography`

I know why I got this error and solved it by downloading the module with `pip install cryptography` but I'm wondering if this will always be the case for anyone that downloads the project and doesn't have the cryptography module.

What if I had a number of modules that trigger that error, will all of them have to be downloaded beforehand (one by one), or is there anyway to get around this problem?

Comment: Generally - yes - you will need to ensure that the computer running your python program has the required dependencies pre-installed. You can facilitate this with a requirements.txt file, or alternatively could look into docker containers as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely look into your suggestions @ScottC